# AdMob - Banner and Interstitial on same activity - OK or not?

Tags: admob

I cannot find any documentation on this. Admob does not allow 2 ads on screen if you have one anchored banner.

I have one anchored banner at the bottom of my screen always present. Between activities I would like to implement an interstitial.

Since the interstitial is called on the activity with the current banner ad - is this allowed, considered two ads on one activity, or separate screens so all good?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can place interstitial ad and banner on same activity provided

1. "You should place no more than one interstitial ad after **every two user actions** within your app. "
2. "interstitial ad is not shown at exit of application"
3. "interstitial ad is not shown at launch of application"

Please read below link for disallowed interstitial implementation

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, Amod!