# Adding AdMob interstitial ads before closing the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I want to display AdMob interstitial ad on exit link from the nav bar and close the app on click of either on the interstitial ad or the close button of the ad.

I am using the following codes but it won't work:

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    void loadAdsFullScreen(){
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad));
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
                .build();
        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                showInterstitial1();
            }
        });
    }
```

The code I am using for closing the app and showing the ads is:

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_exit) {

            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad));
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
                    .build();
            // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request);

            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    showInterstitial();
                    finish();
                }
            });

            Test1.this.finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }
```

Comment: on different note.. don't show advertisements on exit of application  ( i assume by exit in above case is exit from application ). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302244/admob-banner-and-interstitial-on-same-activity-ok-or-not/41305663#41305663

Comment: +1. This is an important point for AdMob policy. An ad should never be the first or last thing a user sees when running your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onAdClosed of listener like,

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                showInterstitial();

            }
             @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
            Activity_Class_Name.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Activity_Class_Name.this.finish();
        }

        });
```

Comment: gives error: `Error:(313, 29) error: not an enclosing class: Activity`

Comment: Replace Activity with your activity_class_name

Comment: Still no ads displaying.

Comment: remove Test1.this.finish(); from else if (id == R.id.nav_exit) {} block

Comment: worked but the ad takes time to load. Is it the coding issue or the internet speed?

Comment: Also how do I close the app if the user clicks on the Ad?

Comment: speed could be an issue but you can make it faster. You can load the ad while activity creates or any time and then show it according this code.

Comment: see updated answer. Need to override onAdOpened() method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't encourage you to do interstitial ads when exiting the app since google Admob privacy policy doesn't allow that.